# How to add two render in Django function views

Tags: django, django-views

How to add two render in single function based views. I don't know this can be done, if not please provide the alternative way of doing this.

**views.py**

```
def success(request):
    return render(request, "tools/loading.html", {})


    #Raspberry pi code
    print("on")
    pin13.write(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("off")
    pin13.write(0)

    return render(request, "tools/booked.html", {})
```

Currently it won't run the raspberry pi code, it directly returns the page and skip the rest of the code down the first render.

But I need to update this code so that when calling this 'success' function based view it should return the 'loading.html', after performing the Raspberry pi code it should return another page. All this should be done in backend.

Answer (score -1):

You can't render two html file in single view. Please use the Django template language for the desired behaivour.

you can include the other template in current template also

```
{% include 'tools/booked.html' %}
```

Comment: This won't do what OP wants, i.e. render one thing, wait, then render another.